# How to get POS tags of compound words with stanford

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I used Stanford POS Tagger to tag parts of speech in a sentence, i used the following code:

```
private static MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(".../english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
String tags= tagger.tagString(st);   //st is a string
```

That gives a result when words are not compound. But what I want is to get the POS Tag of compound words like "go back", computer science", "picking up".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the [tagString](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html#tagString-java.lang.String-) method

*"This method tokenizes the input into words"*

Also, the models are trained to identify and tag words (tokens). Suggested solutions :

1. Write a [custom annotator](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml#custom) that depends on (runs after) the POS tagger and when it finds a compound pattern e.g. "go back" it can annotate the first token with your custom annotator. You can identify these patterns by creating a dictionary and/or matching grammar patterns. The latter may additionally require the [dependency parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml).
2. Use [tokensregex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.shtml). This offers the ability to implement regular expressions that operate on tokens and their annotations instead of characters.
3. Train new models that can identify multi-token or compound words.